# Logout from all tabs when from one tab a user logged out

Tags: visualforce, pagereference, login

I have a requirement like ,i have opened 2 3 tabs.And lets say i logged out from 1st tab.Then without refreshing my other tabs how will the user be redirected on to the login page.
On tab 2nd there is one button.Onclick of that button one vf remoting is executing.I wanted to redirect the user to login page onclicking of the button.
For this,I wrote one pagereference method and call that method on remoting.But it's not working as after logging out controller method is not executing.Is there a way around apart from crating a javascript funtion and adding a function that will execute and check for the user status asynchronously.

vfremoting:

```
@RemoteAction
    global static string callJNMethod(JNReqRespWC.paramWrap param){
        validateAndRedirect(); //method to check user status
        Httpresponse res = new Httpresponse();
        string evelist;
        string endurl;
        List<String> urlValues = param.url.split('/');
        if(param.eventName == urlValues[0])
            endurl = '/'+param.url;
        else
            endurl = '/'+param.eventName+param.url;
        if(endurl.contains('/portal/consent')){
            res = JNUtilClass.JNPost(endurl, param.queryStr);   
        }
        else
            res = JNUtilClass.JNsendReq('GET', endurl, param.queryStr);
        if(res.getBody() != null){
            evelist = res.getBody();
        }
        return evelist;
    }

method:
public static PageReference validateAndRedirect(){
        user u=[select id,isActive from user where id=:userinfo.getuserid()];
        system.debug('user active' +u.IsActive);
        if(!u.isActive){
         PageReference retURL = new PageReference('https://login.salesforce.com');
         retURL.setRedirect(true);
         return retURL;
       }else
         return null;
    }
```

Comment: Is that user able to execute Apex code even after logging out?

Comment: Are you using `isActive` to determine if the user is logged in? That seems to be incorrect because `isActive` determines if the user can login in the system or not and it does not determine user's active session.

Comment: @:pranav After logging out ,remoting is not being called.

Comment: You can't run Apex Code while the user is logged out. For remoting, that means you'll have to detect the error and reload the page, which will trigger the login page automatically.

Comment: @:Jayant Das- Yes, 'isActive'  will tell if user is active or not.Based on that when i logout from separate tab and from current tab when i click on the button redirection should happen, as in remoting i am calling validateAndRedirect() method to redirect.but its not working